# Wishlist controller is not extending to the new file

Tags: wishlist, magento-1.4

NOTE: This is Magento 1.4.  Because of the complex configuration of some of our products, I'm having to route the wishlist function `addAction()` over to the app/code/local section of Magento.  However, the reroute is not taking effect.  Here is what I have done:

1. **created this folder/file:**
   `app/code/local/Mycompany/Wishlist/etc/config.xml`

inside I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Wishlist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Wishlist>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_Wishlist>Mycompany_Wishlist</Mycompany_Wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

2. **created this folder/file:**
   `app/code/local/Mycompany/controllers/IndexController.php`

with this code:

```
require_once 'Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Mycompany_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
{
    /**
     * Adding new item
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        exit('hello world, I'm in the new file!');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            $this->_redirect('*/');
            return;
        }
        .. etc. ..
```

I HAVE CLEARED MY CACHE.  Why is the new file not being recognized?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will be helpful to someone.  I made the following two changes to get it to work:

First: added a file `app/code/etc/modules/Mycompany_Wishlist.xml` so that Mage could recognize the router (and of course cleared my cache):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Wishlist>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Wishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Second: added `before="Mage_Wishlist"` in the XML - see pasted code below - as it appears that without this, the native code is overriding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Wishlist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Wishlist>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">Mycompany_Wishlist</Mycompany_Wishlist>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```